# Create number range from input field

Tags: javascript

I have input field for ZIP, when user fill out field I want create two variables with first ground value.

example:

User type: 01250,
I need two variables with values 01000 and 02000

```
var zip = $('.js-zip-input').val();
var inputZip = zip % 1000;
var zipMax = zip - inputZip + 1000;
var zipMin = zip - inputZip;
```

This working for values when first char isn't 0

Comment: 01250 and 1250 not equal as numbers in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's 'not working' because these are numbers, and it doesn't make sense to have a number 01000. This is really just 1000. If you really need to have the zero, you will have to turn your values into strings and add 0 to the beginning of them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
var zip = 1250;
var range = 1000;

var zipMin = Math.floor(zip/range) * range;
var zipMax = zipMin + range;
```

The code above gets the floor value of the zip input.
You can set up the range value as the difference of both outputs: in your case 1000 to 2000 would have a range of 1000. Give it a try.

As gavin pointed out, you cant have a leading 0 before the output unless you convert them to string. In this case, you can check for the length of the output (as strings) and add leading zeroes.

```
var outputLength = 5;
var zipMinOutput = "0".repeat(outputLength - zipMin.toString().length) + zipMin;
var zipMaxOutput = "0".repeat(outputLength - zipMax.toString().length) + zipMax;
```

The above code adds trailing zeroes for every missing character in the string.

Comment: Great! Good to know. Good luck with what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
var zip = '00000140050';

var zeros = leading_zero(zip.toString().split('').map(Number)); //Number of zeros can be appended to min max values
alert(zeros);
var inputZip = zip % 1000;
var zipMax = zip - inputZip + 1000;
var zipMin = zip - inputZip;

alert(zipMax + ', ' + zipMin);

function leading_zero(x)
{
    var n = 0;  
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
        if (x[i] == 0) n++; 
        else
        break;
    }

    return n;
}

}());
```